# Creating a Sequence with nested ifelse, depending on different Value ranges and NAs, will give wrong result

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a dataframe like this:

```
time  Value  Seq.Count
   1      0          0
   2      0          0
   3      3          0
   4      4          0 
   5      10         0
   6      10         0
   7      10         0
   8      7          0
   9      6          0
  10      NA         0
  11      NA         0
  12      NA         0
  13      0          0
  14      0          0
  15      0          0
```

Now I want the "Seq.Count" col to count one up, every time the number X in the "Value" col changes between any of the following

> 0 == X, 0 < X > 10, X == 10, X == NA

So i want to get something like the following in the end:

```
time  Value  Seq.Count
   1      0          0
   2      0          0
   3      3          1
   4      4          1 
   5      10         2
   6      10         2
   7      10         2
   8      7          3
   9      6          3
  10      NA         4
  11      NA         4
  12      NA         4
  13      0          5
  14      0          5
  15      0          5
```

I wrote this code:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df$Seq.Count[i] <-  ifelse(df$Value[i] == 10,                                                                                 
                                ifelse(df$Value[(i-1)] != 10, df$Seq.Count[i-1]+1, df$Seq.Count[i-1]),                        
                                ifelse(df$Value[i] == 0,                                                                             
                                       ifelse(df$Value[(i-1)] != 0, df$Seq.Count[i-1]+1, df$Seq.Count[i-1]),                   
                                       ifelse(between(df$Value[i], 0.01, 9.99),                                                    
                                              ifelse(df$Value[i-1] == 0 | df$Value[i-1] == 10 | is.na(df$Value[i-1]),   
                                                    df$Seq.Count[i-1]+1,df$Seq.Count[i-1]),                                         
                                              ifelse(is.na(df$Value[i]),                                                             
                                                     ifelse(!is.na(df$Value[i-1]), df$Seq.Count[i-1]+1, df$Seq.Count[i-1]),   
                                                     df$Seq.Count[i-1]                                                                  
                                                     )                                                          
                                              )                                                                                     
                                       ) 
                                )
                           }
```

Now what this will give me is the following:

```
time  Value  Seq.Count
   1      0          0
   2      0          0
   3      3          1
   4      4          1 
   5      10         2
   6      10         2
   7      10         2
   8      7          3
   9      6          3
  10      NA         NA
  11      NA         NA
  12      NA         NA
  13      0          NA
  14      0          NA
  15      0          NA
```

After the first NA occurs in the "Value" col, all following values of the "Seq.Count" col will be NA

Why is this?

according to this line from the code:

```
    ifelse(is.na(df$Value[i]),
           ifelse(!is.na(df$Value[i-1]), df$Seq.Count[i-1]+1, df$Seq.Count[i-1]), ...
```

It sould simply take the value from the

> Seq.Count[i-1]

and add 1 to it, **if**

> is.na(df$Value[i])

and

> !is.na(df$Value[i-1])

Why does this not work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized

Comment: `rep(1:length(rle(ifelse(is.na(df$Value), 1, ifelse(df$Value==0, 2, ifelse(df$Value==10, 3, 4))))$lengths),rle(ifelse(is.na(df$Value), 1, ifelse(df$Value==0, 2, ifelse(df$Value==10, 3, 4))))$lengths)
` how about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution ?

```
tmp <- as.numeric(addNA(cut(df$Value,breaks=c(0,1,9,10),include.lowest=T)))-1
Seq.Count <- cumsum(abs(c(0,diff(tmp)))>0)

cbind(df[,-3],Seq.Count)

   time Value Seq.Count
1     1     0         0
2     2     0         0
3     3     3         1
4     4     4         1
5     5    10         2
6     6    10         2
7     7    10         2
8     8     7         3
9     9     6         3
10   10    NA         4
11   11    NA         4
12   12    NA         4
13   13     0         5
14   14     0         5
15   15     0         5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, use ifelse and create an extra colomn with the previous value for comparison

```
    require(data.table)
    test <- data.table(time = 1:15, 
                       Value = c(0,0,3,4,10,10,10,7,6,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0))
    # Add a column with the previous value
    test[,previous_value := c(NA, test$Value[1: (nrow(test)-1)])]
    # Check which group the previous value belongs
    test[,group_1 := ifelse(is.na(previous_value),4, 
                            ifelse(previous_value == 0,1, 
                                   ifelse(previous_value > 0 & previous_value < 10,2,
                                          ifelse(previous_value == 10, 3, NA))))]
    # Check which group current value belongs
    test[,group_2 := ifelse(is.na(Value),4,
                            ifelse(Value == 0,1, 
                                   ifelse(Value > 0 & Value < 10,2,
                                          ifelse(Value == 10, 3, NA))))]
    # Compare them if they are not equal add 1
    test[, Seq.count := cumsum(group_1 != group_2) - 1]
        test
        time Value previous_value group_1 group_2 Seq.count
     1:    1     0             NA       4       1         0
     2:    2     0              0       1       1         0
     3:    3     3              0       1       2         1
     4:    4     4              3       2       2         1
     5:    5    10              4       2       3         2
     6:    6    10             10       3       3         2
     7:    7    10             10       3       3         2
     8:    8     7             10       3       2         3
     9:    9     6              7       2       2         3
    10:   10    NA              6       2       4         4
    11:   11    NA             NA       4       4         4
    12:   12    NA             NA       4       4         4
    13:   13     0             NA       4       1         5
    14:   14     0              0       1       1         5
    15:   15     0              0       1       1         5
```

Answer (score 0):

### Elaborating on [Marco Sandri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166684/marco-sandri)'s answer

As far as I understand you have several categories of values, say:

- x == 0,       covered by interval [0,0.9]
- 1 <= x <= 9,  covered by interval (0.9,9]
- x == 10,      covered by interval (9, 10]
- x is NA,      NA itself

The code that solves your problem is:

```
w <- cut(df$Value,breaks=c(0,0.9,9,10),include.lowest=T)
w1 <- addNA(w)
r <- w1 != lag(w1)
r[1] <- F
df$Seq.Count <- Reduce('+', r, accumulate = T)
```

### Step by step explanation

The first step is to clasify your data according to the mentioned categories, **cut()** does such a function:

```
(w <- cut(df$Value,breaks=c(0,0.9,9,10),include.lowest=T))
 [1] [0,0.9] [0,0.9] (0.9,9] (0.9,9] (9,10]  (9,10]  (9,10]  (0.9,9] (0.9,9] <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    [0,0.9] [0,0.9] [0,0.9]
Levels: [0,0.9] (0.9,9] (9,10]
```

You need to include NA as Level (catagory) of the result. This is done by **addNA()**, as follows:

```
(w1 <- addNA(w))
 [1] [0,0.9] [0,0.9] (0.9,9] (0.9,9] (9,10]  (9,10]  (9,10]  (0.9,9] (0.9,9] <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    [0,0.9] [0,0.9] [0,0.9]
Levels: [0,0.9] (0.9,9] (9,10] <NA>
```

Then you need to know if there was a change of category between the *current* element of the series and the *previous one*. In order to do this, you need to produce a **lag()** of the series and compare it with the original one:

```
(r <- w1 != lag(w1))
 [1]    NA FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Change the first element to FALSE
r[1] <- F
r
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Notice that the first elemen of the answer, r, is **NA**. Since the first element of the series has nothing to compare with (as there is no previous element), the result for this case should be FALSE. That's the reason r[1] was set to FALSE.

Now you need to sum the TRUE values in the result, preserving the accumulated answers. This is done with **Reduce()**:

```
(df$Seq.Count <- Reduce('+', r, accumulate = T))
 [1] 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

**edit:** You could also have used **cumsum()** instead of **Reduce()**